# Playa Parents entry_id using child ids

Tags: playa

I must be looking at code for too long. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this.

I have a regular page entry, where I select an organization through a playa single select.
An organization entry can have people assigned to it.
I want to show the organization's people on my page entry.

This is my template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}

  Displaying people in organization ID: {related_organization:child_ids}.

  {exp:playa:parents channel="people" entry_id="{related_organization:child_ids}"}
    {title}<br />
    {if no_parents}No results{/if}
  {/exp:playa:parents}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The playa field outside the tag shows me the correct `child_ids`.
The `exp:playa:parents` tag renders no results.
If I hard code the entry ID in the `entry_id` parameter, it works just fine.

If I do `entry_id="4321|1234|{related_organization:child_ids}"`, I can see in my DB queries log that it is not even rendering `{related_organization:child_ids}` at all.
It shows `... WHERE rel.child_entry_id IN (4321,1234) ...`

Adding `parse="inward"` doesn't have any effect.

Why isn't the tag working inside the parameter?

**Update**
Using an embed seems to work. But no one likes embeds anymore.
Using an equivalent stash embed doesn't work.

Comment: Is that your exact code? or dumbed down code? Also (not a great solution) but try passing IDs to an embed. If it's a parsing issue, that will get it working.

Comment: What I posted was what I dumbed my template down to. Still didn't work. Using an embed worked. Using the exact same thing in a stash embed didn't. Whaaaat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a parse order issue, related to the way Playa handles its fieldtype tags.

The Playa fieldtype actually takes its `{related_organization:child_ids}` tag and converts it into a module call: `{exp:playa:child_ids field="related_organization"}`, which the EE parser will then execute. So you are effectively doing this in your template:

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="people" entry_id="{exp:playa:child_ids field='related_organization'}"}
```

You can see why that wouldn't work.

I'd recommend using stash, rather than an embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}

  {exp:stash:set name="child_ids" parse_tags="yes"}
    {related_organization:child_ids}
  {/exp:stash:set}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:parse name="child_ids" process="end" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:playa:parents channel="people" entry_id="{stash:child_ids}"}
    {title}<br />
  {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: My code example was already dumbed down - I've been using Stash for my real template. The shorthand to module tag was the lightbulb moment. Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.

The `{related_organization:child_ids}` is just shorthand for the `{exp:playa:child_ids}` tag pair.

Putting a tag pair inside a parameter was making it freak out.

So instead of using `{related_organization:child_ids}` as the `entry_id` parameter, I did this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}

  {related_organization var_prefix="org"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="people" entry_id="{org:entry_id}"}
      {title}<br />
    {/exp:playa:parents}
  {/related_organization}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Rob explains the same thing [in his answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/13551/100) and recommends how to do it with Stash.